# System.TimeoutException when trying to send EventDataBatch to azure event hub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I have a function app that sends some data to an Azure event hub, but I get the below exception thrown at certain instances.

System.TimeoutException: Creation of RequestResponseAmqpLink did not complete in 0 milliseconds.
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout) at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.TaskHelpers.EndAsyncResult(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Is there a way someone can mitigate this issue? Thanks
For more clarifications i am using EventHubClient.send(EventDataBatch) method

Comment: There isn't much context to work from;  some additional information would be very helpful to understand your scenario.   To start, I'm rather confused by the `Office` reference in the exception type; none of the official Event Hubs SDKs make use of that namespace.  Which SDK are you using?  The exception message also seems to imply creation of a request/response link which is not used for publishing, only for querying information.  What is the host for the application?  Can you share the code for how you're creating your client?

Comment: @JesseSquire I am using 3.1.201 Dotnet SDK, I updated the question to reflect the exception thrown and the app is hosted on Microsoft azure

Comment: I am creating my client by connection string. EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString)

Comment: That exception indicates that the SDK was unable to open an link to the Event Hubs service.  My best guess is that your `Send` operation encountered multiple failures and the last retry exceeded the configured `OperationTimeout` at an awkward point.   Since the operation timeout is applied cumulatively across the entire operation, the attempt to open the link was given a very short timeout to complete, which got rounded to zero.   This can happen due to network instability and transient failures.  If you're seeing this consistently, it may indicate a problem.